# Fast way to enumerate forest and build domain trees?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I need to build a tree of **[domains in a forest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759073%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)**. So far I have used the following code:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;

...

List<Domain> domains = new List<Domain>(); // flat list of domains
foreach (Domain dom in Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains)
{
    try
    {
        domains.Add(dom);
        var de = dom.GetDirectoryEntry();
        // Here I have de.Guid and de.Parent.Guid, so using them I can build a tree
    }
    catch () {} // for simplicity left it blank.
}
```

The code works well. But when some of the domain becomes unavailable, the response (**[Domain.GetDirectoryEntry()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.getdirectoryentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**) can take a while (15-20 sec.) before exception throwing. But using Active Directory Domains and Trusts, it is possible to retrieve all forest trees pretty fast with problem domains, so I suppose that there is some cache of domains somewhere.

**Q**:

If this cache is in the **[Global Catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/how-global-catalog-servers-work%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)**, I wonder - is it possible to have **AD** structure without **GC**?

And how can I perform a faster enumeration of forest domains, and build a tree structure?

Comment: Have you considered using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols?  You can specify the timeout on the SendRequest, IIRC.

Comment: I heard about it. Nevertheless - how can I build a domain trees of the entire forest using it?